# Changing the color of a Button in SwiftUI on tvOS

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, tvos

I am trying to change the color of a SwiftUI `Button` on tvOS.

Modifying the `background` almost works, except that you can see that the underlying `UIButton` is actually using a rounded, translucent image over the top of the background. This results in a different colour at the corners where the rectangular background lies outside the rounded image.

[image]

Adding `.padding` emphasises this issue:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State
    var selected = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.selected.toggle()
        }) {
               Text($selected.wrappedValue ? "On":"Off")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            }.padding(.all)
             .background(self.selected ? Color.green : Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

A related issue is the changing the color of the "focus" view, as I suspect that this is the same view as the button itself, transformed win size and color.

The typical technique in tvOS with a `UIButton` is to change the button image, but there doesn't seem to be any way to access the image of the underlying `UIButton`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again, I have only checked it on iOS, but this should help:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selected = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: { self.selected.toggle() }) {
            Text($selected.wrappedValue ? "On":"Off")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }   .padding(.all)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                            .fill(self.selected ? Color.green : Color.blue))

    }
}
```

You can pass any view into .background() modifier, so you might also want to try placing an Image() in there.

Comment: This works pretty well - I got rid of the `.padding(all)` - that was just in my question to emphasise the issue. I also changed the radius to 8 - with 5 I could still see pixel or so of the underlying colour.  It still looks like `Button` on tvOS needs some work from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

This code seems to work fine on iOS but, as you've shown, in tvOS the underlying UIButton is visible.  I'm not sure how to get at the underlying button or its image, but it seems you can hack it for now (until Apple either fixes the issue or provides a way to get at that button.)

First, move the padding up to modify the Text so that it will properly affect the underlying button.

Second, (and this is the hack) clip the view after the background modifier with a cornerRadius.  As long as the radius is equal to or greater than that of the underlying button, it will clip off the excess background.  (Of course, what you see is not the green Color, but the color resulting from the green color superimposed on the gray of the translucent button image.  At least that's how it's shown in Xcode.)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selected = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.selected.toggle()
        }) {
            Text($selected.wrappedValue ? "On":"Off")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.all)
        }
        .background(self.selected ? Color.green : Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it has a couple of issues - The corner radius is a bit of a guess - if the button is larger then 5 isn't sufficient, but this could be tweaked.  The bigger issue is that as soon as you apply a `cornerRadius` to the button you can't give it focus - it becomes non-selectable.

Comment: Then, you're a step ahead of me.  The button is this code was not selectable for me, with or without the cornerRadius.  I thought it was a bug in Xcode.  I'm at a loss.  I also tried an Image instead of Text for the Button's label, but it has the same issue at the corners.

Comment: The behavior is very weird all around.  In iOS, the button is not selectable with an Image as its label (even when wrapped in a VStack).  But, it _is_ selectable with a Text as its label or both an Image and Text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution for `tvOS` on Swift `5.5`

```
struct TVButton: View {

// MARK: - Variables
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
@State private var buttonScale: CGFloat = 1.0
var title: String?
var bgColor: Color = .white
var action: () -> Void

// MARK: - Body
var body: some View {
    TVRepresentableButton(title: title, color: UIColor(bgColor)) {
        action()
    }
    .focused($isFocused)
    .onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.2)) {
            buttonScale = newValue ? 1.1 : 1.0
        }
    }
    .scaleEffect(buttonScale)
}
}

struct TVRepresentableButton: UIViewRepresentable {

// MARK: - Typealias
typealias UIViewType = UIButton

// MARK: - Variables
var title: String?
var color: UIColor
var action: () -> Void

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: color), for: .normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: color.withAlphaComponent(0.85)), for: .focused)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: color), for: .highlighted)
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.addAction(.init(handler: { _ in action() }), for: .allEvents)
    
    return button
}

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {}
}

extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
}
}
```

now you are able to change Title, background color, scale and handle tap action on `tvOS`

Comment: This is a great solution, except as far as I can tell, the actions do not fire, at least not in tvOS 15

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(.lightGray), for: .normal)
```

You can st it for `.focused` and `.highlighted`

Comment: This question is regarding SwiftUI, not UIKit.  As I noted in the question, if you could access the underlying UIButton you could fix the issue.