# Button appears on top but not pressable

Tags: swiftui

```
public struct Frontside: View
{
  @Binding public var kanatext: String

  public var body: some View
  {
    ZStack{
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 160, height: 160)
        .zIndex(0)

      Text(self.kanatext)
        .font(.title)
        .fontWeight(.black)
        .padding(50)
        .zIndex(1)

      VStack {
        Spacer()
        HStack {

          Button(action: {
            print("button pressed")
          }) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
              .font(.title)
          }
          .mask(Circle())
          .opacity(0.4)



          Button(action: {
            print("button pressed")
          }) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
              .font(.title)
          }
          .mask(Circle())
          .opacity(0.4)
        }
      }
      .zIndex(2)
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code snippet, I have used a Zstack to layer different parts of a flash card, a background, the text, and then correct/incorrect buttons. The uppermost layer are the buttons, which appear correctly, but for some reason they are not actually pressable.

Comment: There's some weird behavior around buttons.  It could be a bug.  I found that a Button is not actionable when its label is an Image.  But, when the label is Text, or both Text and an Image, it works fine.  Some of the problems are shown here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001370/changing-the-color-of-a-button-in-swiftui-on-tvos/58002898#58002898]

Comment: Thank you for that, I realised as well and decided to stop using Buttons and made an image with tap gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using onTapGesture? It might have to do with the fact that you're using a ZStack.

Try something like:

```
Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
    .font(.title)
    .onTapGesture {
       print("button pressed")
    }
```

In this case there would be no needed to wrap the Image in a Button. 
If this doesn't work add `onTapGesture` to your VStack and have it be empty.